# AngularJS: How does directive template get update everytime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I came across the following example and confused about how does the directive template get rendered every time. Here is the code:

```
angular.module("cart",[]).factory("cart", function(){
   var cartData = [];
   return{
    addProduct:function(id, name, price){
     cartData.push({count:1, id:id, price:price, name:name})
    },
    getProduct: function(){
     return cartData;
    }
   };
 }).directive("cartSummary", function(cart){
  return{
   restrict: "E",
   template:"cartSummary.html",
   controller: function($scope){
    var cartData = cart.getProduct();

    $scope.totalPrice = function(){
        var total = 0;
        /*some logic here*/
        return  total;
     }
    }
  }
});
```

the cart Summary.html:

```
<div navbar-text>{{totalPrice()}}</div>
```

and in another module, I have this code to update the cartData:

```
angular.module("store", ["cart"]).controller("storeCtrl", function($scope, cart){
 /*some logic here*/
 $scope.addToCart = function(){
    cart.addProduct(product.id, product.name, product.price);
  }
 });
```

the HTML of the "store" module:

```
 <html ng-app="store">
   <body ng-controller="storeCtrl">
     <!--some html-->
     <cart-summary/>
     <!--some html-->
     <button ng-click="addToCart(item)">Add To Cart</button>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I understand the cartData will get updated every time user clicks the "add to cart" button, but I dont understand how does the function totalPrice() in the directive template get called every time. Does the template get re-rendered? if it is, what trigger the re-rendered? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular watches the scope object for changes, and re-renders the template when the scope is changed. Here's more info on angular scopes: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

**Update**: angular needs to have a scope property to watch so that it can know to re-render the template. Nothing in your example links the directive to the `cartData` object in the service, so the directive won't know about any updates. You could be probably make this work with some combination of `$scope.watch()` and `$scope.apply()`, but it's much simpler to just modify your directive controller to include

```
$scope.data = cart.getProduct();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4dhuvap/1/.

Comment: but scope won't change until the totalPrice() get called, and the totalPrice() only gets called in the template. how does this work? thank you

Comment: actually, `totalPrice()` won't even change the `scope`; it's a read-only function. I've updated my answer with more details and a working jsfiddle.